# 'Duplicate entry' error in DLL when building Desktop Bridge UWP application

Tags: desktop-bridge

I am trying to convert a Windows Forms application to UWP using the Desktop Bridge. Since I have (most of) the source code, I'm attempting the conversion [using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net), as opposed to the [command-line tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter). My application uses some third-party DLLs whose source code I don't have.

After adding a new JavaScript UWP project to my solution, I'm placing the original application's DLLs in a project subfolder as explained in the documentation.
Some of these DLLs are causing strange errors when I build the UWP project. The errors seem to be caused by duplicate resource entries in the DLLs, but curiously enough, these DLLs are referenced without issue in my standard Windows Forms project.

The errors state:

- Duplicate entry
- 'DevExpress.Data.PropertyNamesRes/DevExpress/XtraPrinting/XpsDocumentOptions'
  or one of its parents is defined as both resource and scope, which is
  not allowed

I've been digging and searching about these errors for hours but I haven't found any meaningful information. I also used ILDASM to analyze the DLL headers but found no obvious issues in them. Has anyone here faced similar issues? Thanks in advance for any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the complete error is difficult to say, but I've seen similar errors processing resources. If this is the case, this could be the same as this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/issues/8#issuecomment-266912073)

And can be solved adding this property to the jsproj:

```
<AppxGeneratePrisForPortableLibrariesEnabled>false</AppxGeneratePrisForPortableLibrariesEnabled>
```